# Color is not applying in JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, actionlistener, jtextfield

I am developing Java Swing app. In my application I used JPanels and put white color to the background but it is not working properly. Cant guess why? And Same issue on JPanel border.
I tried several times but failed. Evan I am developing in netbeans its not working. Can you help me?

```
public class RegistrationForm extends JFrame {


    public RegistrationForm() {

         initComponents();
         pack();
         setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         this.setVisible(true);

    }   

    private void initComponents() {

        setUndecorated(true);
        jCheckBoxMenuItem1 = new JCheckBoxMenuItem();
        jPanel1 = new JPanel();
        headingLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        conditionTextBox = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        joinButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        firstNameField = new PlaceholderTextField();
        emailField = new PlaceholderTextField();
        userNameField = new PlaceholderTextField();
        passWordField = new PlaceholderPasswordField();
        confirmPassWordField = new PlaceholderPasswordField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();





        jCheckBoxMenuItem1.setSelected(true);
        jCheckBoxMenuItem1.setText("jCheckBoxMenuItem1");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jPanel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
        jPanel1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        headingLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24));
        headingLabel.setText("Join Us Now");

        conditionTextBox.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 11)); 
        conditionTextBox.setText("I agree to the UAC system terms of service and regulations ");


        joinButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 14)); 
        joinButton.setText("Join");
        joinButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                joinButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        firstNameField.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 18)); 


        emailField.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 18)); 


        userNameField.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 18)); 
        userNameField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                userNameFieldActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        passWordField.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 18)); 

        confirmPassWordField.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 18)); 


        jButton1.setActionCommand("closeRegistretion");

       //then adding components                   


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JCheckBox conditionTextBox;
    private PlaceholderPasswordField confirmPassWordField;
    private PlaceholderTextField emailField;
    private PlaceholderTextField firstNameField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel headingLabel;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem jCheckBoxMenuItem1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JButton joinButton;
    private PlaceholderPasswordField passWordField;
    private PlaceholderTextField userNameField;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable by reduce to only only JComponent added to JPanel inside JFrame

Comment: What about setOpaque()?

Comment: setOpaque() is not working too..:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code,In this code we make a panel with background color:-

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class NewClass1 extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{
    public NewClass1() {            
         setLayout(null);
         JPanel panel=new JPanel();
         panel.setOpaque(true);
         add(panel);
         panel.setBackground(Color.red);
         panel.setBounds(0,0,400,300);
    }    

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewClass1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add JPanel to your frames content pane.something like

```
getContentPane().add(jPanel1);
```

Comment: Strange, i could not find any code statement which adds your panel to the frame ! More over you have called setBackgrounColor() method on frame and not the panel. You have accepted answer from mKorble,which essentially doing setOpaque(true), which you already said not working in your above comment !